# iPhone 4 will not connect to any computer and will not show up in device manager

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

My iPhone 4 will not connect to my computer or iTunes anymore after I updated to the new iTunes, and I have looked in other threads and posts and no one seems to have the same issue.

I see other posts about it not connecting, and it says to go into "Device Manager" and find the iPhone under "Portable Devices" but the Portable Devices tab isn't even in my Device Manager on my Laptop (windows 7).

I've deleted all apple appliances on my computer and re-installed iTunes and that didn't work. it's not the cable cord because my iPhone WILL charge while plugged in to my computer, it just will not connect.

and I've looked for an iPhone 4 Apple driver to re-install on my computer but no luck, and also tried plugging it into a different computer to see if it will connect and it still will not.

Please help, I cannot afford to fix this if it is an internal problem with my phone, it has to be a driver on my computer

Comment: you said "any computer" did you tray a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Lets do some troubleshooting.

Verify that Apple Mobile Device Support is installed on your Windows laptop.

iOS devices require Apple Mobile Device Support, which should be automatically installed with iTunes. To verify whether it is installed, follow the steps appropriate for your Windows operating system. (7)

```
Click Start.
Choose Control Panel.
Click "Uninstall a program".
Verify that Apple Mobile Device Support is visible in the list of currently installed programs.
```

If not there, re-install iTunes.